# Cynical vampire and her underwear-stealing lover

Tags: story-identification, vampire

I remember reading a series of three books where the female protagonist was a vampire and she was basically just trying to live her new life... death... undeath?

Anyway, she lived in a sort of small mansion together with her dog and she had a few friends. I think a male human and a female werewolf. I think those two were together. I remember that the werewolf was always described by the protagonist as very beautiful and when she got pregnant and was quit sickly in the morning the protagonist remarked something like:

> She was still abnormally beautiful. The only thing giving me a sense of satisfaction was the fact that she had to barf at the smell of cookies. Poor thing. More cookies for me, though.

Sadly I can't reproduce the dry humour of the protagonist. [Bartimäus was nothing against her.](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/170449/78134)

The humour is the main reason I want to read the books again and the thing that is the hardest to describe, so I will try to mention as many scenes I can remember.

Later she met a male vampire and they fell in love. Maybe he was the one who turned her into a vampire originally? Whenever they had a moment for themselves she afterwards couldn't find her underwear anymore.

At the end of one book she was fighting another vampire and her werewolf friend mentioned that the other vampire tried to poison her dog. The human remarks:

> She tried to steal her house, kill her when she was a human, kill her again when she was a vampire and you think that trying ot poison her dog would make a difference?

The protagonist starts to growl "You tried to poison my dog!!" and puts a stake through her enemies heart. It was pretty funny because the list I tried to replicate above was quite a bit longer and the fight was already pretty long at that point.

She had interesting descriptions of her dog. Something like:

> He was a crossbreed - the result of a wild night between Scooby-Doo and a beanbag chair.

When the protagonist finds out how she died the night someone made her a vampire she is not really sad that she died - instead she is ashamed that a drunk hunter mistook her for a deer in the night on a lone road and shot her when she was walking home alone.

I think she was working in a library.

I've read these books in German, maybe 5 years ago. The titles contained words like "Gut" (*good*) and "Böse" (*evil*). I don't think the books were more than a few years old at that point.

Can you help me remember the names of these books?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is [Nice Girls Don't Have Fangs](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/5618698-nice-girls-don-t-have-fangs?ac=1&from_search=true) by Molly Harper.

> Maybe it was the Shenanigans gift certificate that put her over the edge. When children's librarian and self-professed nice girl Jane Jameson is fired by her beastly boss and handed twenty-five dollars in potato skins instead of a severance check, she goes on a bender that's sure to become Half Moon Hollow legend. On her way home, she's mistaken for a deer, shot, and left for dead. And thanks to the mysterious stranger she met while chugging neon-colored cocktails, she wakes up with a decidedly unladylike thirst for blood.
>
> Jane is now the latest recipient of a gift basket from the Newly Undead Welcoming Committee, and her life-after-lifestyle is taking some getting used to. Her recently deceased favorite aunt is now her ghostly roommate. She has to fake breathing and endure daytime hours to avoid coming out of the coffin to her family. She's forced to forgo her favorite down-home Southern cooking for bags of O negative. Her relationship with her sexy, mercurial vampire sire keeps running hot and cold. And if all that wasn't enough, it looks like someone in Half Moon Hollow is trying to frame her for a series of vampire murders. What's a nice undead girl to do?

I believe the werewolf girl who marries her best friend occurs in a later book (there are 4 directly in the series).  Lots of books by the author tie-in somehow.

Comment: ^_^ Nice! How did you find this one?

Comment: @FuzzyBoots I recognized it.  Read them all.  As Secespitus said, the humor/snarkiness is quite funny.  I think the Kentucky setting caught me at first (but it is set closer to Ashland than Lexington).  The whole set of books is fun, I just skip the romance/sex scenes.

Comment: *blink* I grew up in Ashland. I'll have to check that one out.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots I knew you were from Ashland, but I was thinking east instead of west.  Apparently it is set in what is essentially Paducah.

Comment: FWIW, while Molly Harper has written several books set in Half Moon Hollow (or following peripheral stories), she also has other romance books, some supernatural and some not. :) I've enjoyed most of them that I've read. She's got an entertaining style.